# Identifying dynamic host and port for ATG Web Service created through Create Web Service Wizard

Tags: web-services, atg, atg-dynamo

I am using ATG 10.2 with Weblogic server. I have created a Repository web service (getRepositoryItem) using the Web Services Wizard through dyn admin. I left the host and port empty during the EAR creation. My service is up with the EAR now, but according to the documentation for ATG web services, it says the host and port would be provided on run time. I have not provided any security setting for the webservice but it shows me a 403 if I try to hit the context for the servlet for the service.

I am struggling to access the web service. In the Manage Web services through dyn admin I see my WebApp deployed. But its *Instance Running and Registered* is displayed as false.

Documentation tells that if the service has been executed *Instance Running and Registered* displays as true.

Could somebody please help in answering, **How to access the web service?**

Comment: Have you checked that the service is exposed in your web.xml? Are you going through a webserver? If so, try to hit ATG directly and see if it works then.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the service is exposed in web.xml and I am able to see the wsdl too. But not sure how to hit that wsdl through a browser. I am not going through a webserver. It is my dev environment where I am directly hitting weblogic. I am not sure how ATG provides the port directly and how would I know what to hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the url as follows it will work. I just had to use the name twice.

http://host:port/serviceName/serviceName?WSDL